# Maven Codehaus findbugs plugin "onlyAnalyze" option not working as expected

Tags: java, maven, build, findbugs, mojo

**Update for the impatient:** it's simple, use `package.-` for sub-package scanning instead of `package.*`, as-per martoe's answer below!

I cannot seem to get `onlyAnalyze` working for my multi-module project: regardless of what package (or pattern) I set, maven-findbugs-plugin doesn't evaluate sub-packages as I'd expect from passing it packagename.*.

To prove either myself or the plugin at fault (though I always assume it's the former!), I setup a small Maven project with the following structure:

```
pom.xml
src/
    main/java/acme/App.java
    main/java/acme/moo/App.java
    main/java/no_detect/App.java
```

which is very simple!

The POM has the following findbugs configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals><goal>findbugs</goal><goal>check</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <onlyAnalyze>acme.*</onlyAnalyze>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and every App.java has the following code with two obvious violations:

```
package acme;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class App implements Serializable
{
    private static final class NotSer {
        private String meh = "meh";
    }

    private static final NotSer ns = new NotSer();// Violation: not serializable field

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ns.meh = "hehehe";// Vilation: unused
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Note that `no_detect.App` has the same content as above, but my expectation is that it wouldn't be evaluated by findbugs because I have the "onlyAnalyze" option set to `acme.*` which I assume would evaluate `acme.App` and `acme.moo.App` and nothing else.

I now execute a `mvn clean install` to clean, build, test, run findbugs, package, install, which produces the following findbugs report (snipped for brevity) and results in a build failure which is expected because `acme.App` and `acme.moo.App`:

```
<BugInstance category='BAD_PRACTICE' type='SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID' instanceOccurrenceMax='0'>
<ShortMessage>Class is Serializable, but doesn't define serialVersionUID</ShortMessage>
<LongMessage>acme.App is Serializable; consider declaring a serialVersionUID</LongMessage>
<Details>
  &lt;p&gt; This field is never read.&amp;nbsp; Consider removing it from the class.&lt;/p&gt;
</Details>
<BugPattern category='BAD_PRACTICE' abbrev='SnVI' type='SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID'><ShortDescription>Class is Serializable, but doesn't define serialVersionUID</ShortDescription><Details>
<BugCode abbrev='UrF'><Description>Unread field</Description></BugCode><BugCode abbrev='SnVI'><Description>Serializable class with no Version ID</Description></BugCode>
```

To summarise: only `acme.App` is analysed, `acme.moo.App` isn't (bad) and neither is `no_detect.App` (good).

I tried with two wildcards in the `onlyAnalyze` option but that produces a **successful build** but with a findbugs error (`Dangling meta character '*'` etc).

I tried with `onlyAnalyze` set to `acme.*,acme.moo.*` which analyzes all the expected classes (`acme.App` and `acme.moo.App`) which means it "works" but not as I expect; i.e. I have to explicitly declare all parent-packages for the classes I want to analyze: that could get large and difficult to maintain on a multi-module project!

Do I have to define every package I want analyzed, or can I declare a wildcard/regex pattern that will do what I want?

I'd rather not use the inclusion/exclusion XML because that requires far more setup and reasoning that I don't currently have time for...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To cite the [Findbugs manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#commandLineOptions): "Replace .* with .- to also analyze all subpackages"

Comment: In my frustration and frantic searching I managed to not actually RTFM - though to be fair I never actually found that documentation myself. Thanks!